# DVI to VGA converter not working (Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller)

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, intel-graphics, dvi

I have two monitors on my PC, the first one connected by VGA and the second one connected using DVI-D. I just bought a new monitor which only allows VGA connection, so i bought a DVI-D to VGA converter in order to connect it as second monitor. However the DVI-D is not recognizing the connection so when i use xrandr to explore connected devices I only obtain the VGA connected monitor.

I am using the graphic device included in the motherboard (Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller). And this is the output that I obtain when using xrandr with the old monitor connected to DVI output:

> Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 3200 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
>
> DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
>
> DP2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
>
> HDMI1 connected 1280x1024+0+56 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
>
> 338mm x 270mm
>      1280x1024     60.02*+  75.02
>      1280x960      60.00
>      1280x800      59.91
>      1152x864      75.00
>      1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94
>      1024x768      75.08    70.07    60.00
>      832x624       74.55
>      800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25
>      720x576       50.00
>      720x480       60.00    59.94
>      640x480       75.00    72.81    66.67    60.00    59.94
>      720x400       70.08
>
> HDMI2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
>
> VGA1 connected primary 1920x1080+1280+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
>
> 477mm x 268mm
>      1920x1080     60.00*+
>      1680x1050     59.95
>      1400x1050     59.98
>      1600x900      60.00
>      1280x1024     75.02    60.02
>      1440x900      59.89
>      1280x800      59.81
>      1152x864      75.00
>      1280x720      60.00
>      1024x768      75.08    60.00
>      800x600       75.00    60.32
>      640x480       75.00    60.00
>      720x400       70.08
>
> VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)

It's extrange because it should be using the VIRTUAL1 and not the HDMI1 no? Shall i buy a new DVI-D to VGA converter or it's a configuration problem?

Thank you

P.S: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Comment: Replace the converter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your converter. If there is no bulky conversion area (aside from normal sized heads), it is probably a fake cable, especially if bought off eBay.

This is because the digital (DVI-D) signal cannot be just 'rewired' into an analog signal (VGA), and instead must be converted using circuitry.